# Printer setup incomplete because of a metered connection

Tags: windows-10, printer, dell-inspiron, hp-deskjet

I tried to set up my HP Deskjet 3510 printer on my Dell Inspiron Windows 10 laptop. The printer is connected with the laptop with a USB 2.0 cable. Laptop is connected to a home WiFi network. After installing the driver, the printer is not able to print, not can it be set as the default printer. There's a message saying

> setup incomplete because of a metered connection.

I've tried to remove the printer and connect again. This never happened before. Can anyone tell me what it means and how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The printer is trying to connect to the Internet through your laptop, perhaps to check for firmware upgrades.

See http://windows.microsoft.com/en-my/windows-8/metered-internet-connections-frequently-asked-questions how to enable that:

> 1. Swipe in from the right edge of the screen, tap Settings, and then tap Change PC settings.
>      (If you're using a mouse, point to the upper-right corner of the screen, move the mouse pointer down, click Settings, and then click Change PC settings.)
> 2. Tap or click PC and devices.
> 3. Tap or click Devices, and then tap or click the toggle under Download over metered connections.
>
> Once you've finished downloading your devices updates, you can turn this setting off to avoid unexpected charges when you're on a metered network.

Comment: Why does the printer wants to connect to the Internet? If I connect it to the router using an internet cable, will that solve the problem?

Comment: In Windows 10, search "Connected Device Settings" to get to the right spot in the Control Panel.